# How to increment based on user input

Tags: python-3.x

On the code below I want to add at the end of (Please enter number of cases for {}) of week 1 based on the input I get from the user here

```
number = int(input("How many weeks would you like to look at: "))
```

So if they enter  3 above.

The code below will run through Monday - Sunday of week 1 and then do the same but ask for week 2 then week 3

```
for i in range (number):
        days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day in days:
            while True:
                try:
                    case = int(input("Please enter number of cases for {} ".format(day)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not the whole code, this is just the part I think it need to be added on to.  What I need is for the case Input to say "Please enter number of cases for Monday of week 1"  Then if the use input 2 for example once it runs through the days of week 1, it will then ask for the days of week 2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So currently you have a try-except statement, but you’re missing the except part. So at the bottom, put:

```py
except:
    # whatever you want here
```

Then inside the `try` block you want to break out of your infinite while loop, if the user entered a valid number.

So overall:

```py
number = int(input("How many weeks would you like to look at: "))

for i in range (number):
        days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day in days:
            while True:
                try:
                    case = int(input("Please enter number of cases for {} ".format(day)))
                    break
                except:
                    print("enter a valid number")
```

Edit:

I would use string formatting here, the `%s` is a placeholder for a string, and the `%d` is a placeholder for an integer.

```py
number = int(input("How many weeks would you like to look at: "))

for i in range (number):
        days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day in days:
            while True:
                try:
                    case = int(input("Please enter number of cases for %s of Week %d " %(day, i+1)))
                    break
                except:
                    print("enter a valid number")
```

Comment: Sorry I had more to the code, I was just showing the part I wanted to add to.

Comment: Did the break statement fix your issue though? Or is there another issue?

Comment: What I need is for the case Input to say "Please enter number of cases for Monday of week 1" Then if the use input 2 for example once it runs through the days of week 1, it will then ask for the days of week 2,

Comment: I’ve edited my original post, see if that’s what you want